# UNIX Sed Command to Replace ` with '

Tags: shell, unix, sed

My file `test.csv` contain Record `` `Ashish` ``. I want to globally replace it with single quote `'Ashish'`.

I tried this command:

```
sed 's/`/'/g' test.csv
```

but it is not working. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tr is the right tool to replace characters:

```
echo '`' | tr \` \'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes `"` on the outside and escaping the backtic.

```
sed "s/\`/'/g" Test.in > Test.out
```

Also, if you want to change the original file, you have to use the `-i` flag.

```
sed -i "s/\`/'/g" Test.in
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `'` and `` ` `` characters:

```
sed s/\'/\`/g test.csv > out.csv
```

Comment: You're doing more than that - you're removing the script delimiter `'`s too, otherwise you couldn't escape a `'` within a `'`-delimited script but by doing that and not replacing with double quotes you're having to now escape the backtick too.

Answer (score 0):

The *reason* that fails is because it is not possible to place a single quote in a single quoted string: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes

The workaround is this:

- `` sed 's/`/'"'"'/g' ``

  - concatenate a single-quoted string (`` 's/`/' ``) with a double-quoted string (`"'"`) and another single-quoted string (`'/g'`), or
- `` sed 's/`/'\''/g' ``

  - concatenate a single-quoted string with a literal single quote and another single-quoted string, or
- other quoting strategies given in other  answers